# Validation on Custom Fields on registration widget in sitefinity MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, widget, sitefinity

I am using Front End MVC Register and Login Widget I have 2 Issues with it.

1) I have custom fields which I have added them with User Profile. they work well but problem is that we are unable to validate any field from profile.

2) We need to use recaptcha but as recaptcha requires server side to validate the response. in this case we are unable to validate

if you have any heads up Pleas let me know.

Thank you
Chandresh

Answer (score 0):

1) As for the custom fields on the register widget you can access them on the `Model.Profile` dictionary. So for client side validation you would just check

```
@if((Model.Profile.ContainsKey("YourCustomFieldName")) && Model.Profile["YourCustomFieldName"] == null){                         
   <div class="has-error">
      <span class="help-block">Some Error message about field not being entered</span>
   </div> 
}
```

2) To handle server side actions just extend the `RegistrationModel` and rebind it in Global.asax to your newly created model. You can learn more about this here https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/extend-the-model-of-built-in-widgets-mvc